# Understanding a strong pointer and out of scope

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wanted to understand the following scenario

```
-(void) foo
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                       message:@"Could not save file"
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];

       [alert show]; 

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   //This is called when ok is pressed
}
```

In the above code a `UIAlertView` strong pointer is created and a delegate to self is assigned. The reason I called it a strong reference pointer is because it is created in scope and will go out of scope when its reference count goes to 0. I believe the reference count goes to 0 when the method `foo` ends then why am I still getting a callback at `clickedButtonAtIndex` ? I was under the assumption that we would not get a callback because the destructor of the alertView instance would have been called as soon as the method `foo` ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe the reference count goes to 0

You believe wrong. When you say `[alert show]`, you hand the alert object over to Cocoa, which retains it; otherwise there would be no alert view to appear on the screen! That alert view has a reference (which is actually weak) to you (`self`). And Cocoa thus is able to hand the very same alert view back to you in the delegate callback; the alert is still alive because Cocoa is still retaining it, and you are still alive because you are still alive, so the reference to `self` works as the target of the callback.

Also, I can't quite tell whether you grasp that as soon as you say `[alert show]`, the code does *not pause* - it goes right on, immediately. Thus the first method is *over* before the alert actually appears on the screen. Again, this works because the alert has been handed over to Cocoa, which retains it and takes care of showing it on the next runloop. None of *your* code is running while the alert is present on the screen.

A completely parallel situation is

```
MyViewController* vc = [MyViewController new];
[self.presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The code ends, so why doesn't MyViewController vanish in a puff of smoke? Because `presentViewController` hands it over to Cocoa, which inserts it into the view controller hierarchy and retains it.

Comment: And see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_view_controller_and_view_creation

Comment: And of course there are _lots_ situations where you hand an object over to Cocoa and Cocoa retains it: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_how_cocoa_objects_manage_memory

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up - Marked as the answer after the timer